# How do I use a grep command to display lines that only have a space character?

Tags: unix

I have a file called test01 it currently contains:

```
1  Line one.$
2    This is the second line. $
3       The third  $
4  $
5    This    is    really line 4,  with one         blank line before. $
6  $
7  $
8   $
9  Five$
10  $
11 Line 6 is this.
12     Seven $
13 $
14 Eighth real line. $
15 $
16 $
17   Line 9 $
18     Line   10   is   the  last$
19 $
20                      $
```

I need to write a grep command that will only output lines that contain a space character. It shouldn't output lines such as 4 or 6. The desired output should be lines 8, 10 and 20. I've tried `grep -vn '[a-z,A-Z,0-9]' test01` however I get the lines that do not contain characters.

Comment: Have you tried `grep ' ' test01`?

Comment: Yes however, I get lines 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 18, and 20. However I only want lines 8, 10, and 20

Comment: So ... you want to select lines that contain only whitespace or only space characters?

Comment: Only space characters, so it should output lines 8, 10, and 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern `^ +$`:

```
grep -E '^ +$' filename.txt
```

Use `-n` if you want to get line number:

```
$ egrep -E -n '^ +$' filename.txt
8:
10:
20:
```

Comment: Using this I get a no such file or directory for `'^ +$'` and it outputs any line with a space character, so it also outputs the lines with normal characters in them

Comment: @RyanSisson, Did you replace `filename.txt` with actual filename?  See  http://asciinema.org/a/6636

Comment: yeah I replace it with `test01` which is the name of the file

Comment: Hmm.. How about `grep '^  *$' filename.txt` (double space between `^` and `*`) ?

Answer (score 1):

`grep -n "^ +$" test01`

The `^` means "line starts with", then a space with a `+` sign, which means "one or more spaces", then the `$` means line ends with.  So it matches **only** lines with **only** spaces

Comment: This works however it won't output line 20 because it contains more than 1 space. But I do now get lines 8 and 10

Comment: Oops, silly me.  There ya go.  Unfortunately, no my answer is almost identical to @falsetru's.